# What is webpartid2?

Tags: web-part, office-365

For example I have html for webpart like this:

```
<div class="ms-WPBody noindex " id="WebPartWPQ2" 
    webpartid="7de980df-9385-4e4c-9dc2-a518e968df1c"  
    webpartid2="4cb90c96-ea5a-41db-ac5b-6770451267a5">
```

what is the difference between webpartid and webpartid2 ?

Comment: Hi - I have rearranged the code a little so that now you don't need to scroll to view all the line.